# How to change the backup location of multiple iOS devices using symlink?

Tags: backup, symlink, iphone, ipad

This article outline the steps to take in order to move your iPhone or iPad backups to an external hard drive...

https://www.imore.com/how-move-your-iphone-or-ipad-backups-external-hard-drive

What I'm unclear on is how to handle changing the backup location of **multiple** iOS devices, in my case two iPhones and an iPad.

Do following steps like those outlined here change the backup location for all iOS devices at once?  Or do steps like these need to be somehow repeated for each device?

Comment: If I understand well the page you posted, ou can either move the folder containing the backups of all devices or only the device backup you want to put in external drive. The procedure does not directly change the backup location : it uses a Unix possibility to “fool” the system , by making it think it is writing somewhere but in fact write somewhere else. On windows this can be done through aliases (I used it to use D: instead of C: for iTunes music library without having to reconfigure iTunes)